# mktemp in a docker container fails, but touch works

Tags: permissions, docker, nfs

I am in a docker container, with an NFS volume mapped.  In a directory inside the volume, I can create files by `touch` or other methods, but not using `mktemp`:

```
$ ls -ld /home/share/scripts/converth264queue/
drwxrwxr-x 1 abc abc 964 Oct 22 08:04 /home/share/scripts/converth264queue/
$ touch /home/share/scripts/converth264queue/test2
$ ls -l /home/share/scripts/converth264queue/test2
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc abc 10 Oct 22 08:04 /home/share/scripts/converth264queue/test2
$ cat > /home/share/scripts/converth264queue/test3
test
etst

$ mktemp -p /home/share/scripts/converth264queue file.XXXXXXXX
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/home/share/scripts/converth264queue/file.XXXXXXXX’: Permission denied
$ mktemp -p /home/share/scripts/converth264queue
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/home/share/scripts/converth264queue/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: Permission denied
$ id
uid=1000(abc) gid=100(abc) groups=100(abc),1000(users)
$ ls -lnd /home/share/scripts/converth264queue/
drwxrwxr-x 1 1000 100 964 Oct 22 08:04 /home/share/scripts/converth264queue/
```

Any ideas why this would occur?

Note, mktemp in the docker is provided by coreutils so no setuid:

```
$ ls -ld $(which mktemp)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Oct 20 09:09 /bin/mktemp -> ../usr/bin/coreutils
$ ls -ld /usr/bin/coreutils
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1065928 May  1 21:44 /usr/bin/coreutils
```

Comment: (1) I would get a better feeling about your question if you would demonstrate that *some* commands work with a full pathname; e.g., `touch /home/share/scripts/converth264queue/test`, `cat > /home/share/scripts/converth264queue/test2`, and even ``ls -ld /home/share/scripts/converth264queue``.  (2) It probably won’t really help in this case, but, as a general rule, when a command fails unexpectedly / mysteriously, it’s a good idea to `echo $?` to see whether that tells you anything or gives you a clue.  (3) Does this problem occur only in `/home/share/scripts/converth264queue`?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  What experimentation have you done?  Where does it occur and not occur?  The fact that you have demonstrated it in a directory whose name is 36 characters long (nine times as long as `/tmp`, for example) makes the question hard to read (requires horizontal scrolling) and makes commenting awkward.  (4) Is there any possibility that `mktemp` is setuid on your system?  Do `ls -ld $(which mktemp)`.  (5a) `ls` ignores `-a` when you specify `-d` (i.e., `ls -lad` is equivalent to `ls -ld`).  (5b) `ls -n` implies `-l` (i.e., `ls` ignores `-l` when you specify `-n`).

Comment: Yeah the error code is just `1`.  I am wondering if there is something in the collision free guarantee that mktemp provides that means it needs greater access than can be provided across a docker mapped nfs volume.